# iOS7 - UIAlertView with animated text

Tags: ios7, uialertview, animated

Can we display animation on the `UIAlertView`. Instead of showing just static text in the alert like "This is an alert...", can we have animated text after each second like

```
"This is an alert"
"This is an alert.."
"This is an alert...."
"This is an alert......"
"This is an alert"
"This is an alert.."
```

and so on until the alert view is dismissed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` and `message` attributes are the only properties on `UIAlertView` that you can change after the alert shows, so yes:

```
alert.title = @"New title";
alert.message = @"New message";
```

Comment: How can I change it after every second?